# How to find a word with the most "a" letters?

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

I've got a question how to effectively find a word in a list which has e.g. most "a" letters.
Should I use maxBy somehow or something else?

```
val list1 = List("abdbadaaa", "agdqer", "hjqwk", "vcafqa")
```

Comment: What have you tried? with it didn't work? Do you have some restrictions like it has to be done using recursion or something?

Answer (score 2):

`maxByOption` would be safer because your list might be empty.

```scala
list1.maxByOption(_.count(_ == 'a'))
```

Comment: could you build it up for me? As I don't know what could hide under those "_". I'd be grateful

Comment: @squall It's equivalent to `list1.maxByOption(s => s.count(c => c == 'a'))`